# Show that $g^{(3)}$ has zero when $g$ is $C^3$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $g$ is $C^3$ on $(p,q)$, and $g$ has four zeroes in $(p,q)$. Show that $g^{(3)}$ has a zero.

---

Thoughts:

We are given 4 zeroes "points", say $a,b,c,d$ such that $g(a) = g(b) = g(c) = g(d) = 0$

I was thinking does this have anything to do with Rolle's theorem?

and all we need to prove if $g$ is continuous to apply that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose without loss of generality $a<b<c<d$. Then by Rolle's theorem $g'$ has a zero $x$ between $a$ and $b$, and a zero $y$ between $b$ and $c$ and a zero $z$ between $c$ and $d$.

But then, by Rolle's theorem again, $g''$ has a zero between $x$ and $y$ ...

Comment: Can you get why $g$ needs to be $C^3$?

Comment: @Paul: You need to show that all the functions you need to apply Rolle to satisfy the assumptions of the theorem. $\mathcal C^3$ is slightly more than you need for that, but only slightly (and is easier to state than a weaker condition that worked would be).